# What is the use of the libobjc.A.dylib framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, frameworks

What is the use of the libobjc.A.dylib framework???

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to go with my first instinct and say that it contains the Objective-C runtime systems and such.